# Batch programming Help - not working as expected

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a number of CSV files in directory "C:\Paypal_EMT\data" that I need to process and extract certain data columns based on the first column.

But I'm getting the following error "The system cannot find the file C:\Paypal_EMT\data\STL-20130614.01.005.CSV"

```
C:\Paypal_EMT\data\STL-20130614.01.005.CSV
C:\Paypal_EMT\data\STL-20130615.01.005.CSV
C:\Paypal_EMT\data\STL-20130616.01.005.CSV
....

And data file looks as follows:
"RH",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"FH",01
"SH",2013/06/14 00:00:00 -0400,2013/06/14 23:59:59 -0400,"LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",""
"CH","TransactionID","InvoiceID","PayPalReferenceID","PayPalReferenceIDType","TransactionEventCode","TransactionInitiationDate","TransactionCompletionDate","TransactionDebitOrCredit","GrossTransactionAmount","GrossTransactionCurrency","FeeDebitOrCredit","FeeAmount","FeeCurrency","CustomField","ConsumerID","PaymentTrackingID"
....

Here's my code so far:

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Set path directory where csv files reside in variable
Set _InputPath=C:\Paypal_EMT\data

FOR %%I IN (!_InputPath!\*.CSV) DO ( 

   Set "_OutFile=%%I.sum.rpt"

   FOR /F "tokens=1-18* delims=," %%A IN (!I!) DO (
     if "%%~A"=="RH" echo %%~B
     if "%%~A"=="FH" echo %%~B
     if "%%~A"=="SH" echo %%~B
     if "%%~A"=="CH" echo %%~B,%%~Q,%%~R
     if "%%~A"=="RF" echo %%~B,%%~Q,%%~R
    )

) > %_OutFile%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Set path directory where csv files reside in variable
Set "_InputPath=C:\Paypal_EMT\data"

FOR %%x IN ("%_InputPath%\*.CSV") DO ( 

   Set "_OutFile=%%~x.sum.rpt"

   (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-18* delims=," %%A IN ("%%~x") DO (
     if "%%~A"=="RH" echo %%~B
     if "%%~A"=="FH" echo %%~B
     if "%%~A"=="SH" echo %%~B
     if "%%~A"=="CH" echo %%~B,%%~Q,%%~R
     if "%%~A"=="RF" echo %%~B,%%~Q,%%~R
    ))>"!_OutFile!"
)
```

Comment: Hmm - I'd be tempted to include a USEBACKQ in that there inner loop myself...want to add the two "why it didn't works" ? 'Fraid I didn't see the dots in the filenames - thought they were spaces... specks on me specs... :(

Comment: Yes, this forgotten `usebackq`  is a very common beginner error. Thank you soo much :-) !

Comment: @Peter - I tested the updated code but it didn't work.  I edited your post with my comments.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Peter - I added usebackq as you suggested and it's working now.  Thank you and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's Endoro's work - I just tinkered with it. Actually, I'm a little surprised... I'd have eexpected the output file to need to be specified as `>"%%~x.sum.rpt"` not `>"%_OutFile%"` as this latter should to my mind be resolved on parsing the OUTER loop. I'd even doubt `>"!_OutFile!"` - but if it works, it works! :)

Comment: you are right, this **can not** work, next case for the beginner :(

Comment: Thank you Endoro - Sorry I got confused by the comment but it was actually you that provided the code.

Comment: Sorry Guys - when I tested the code, I removed the part where it write to an output file but it's not working using either >"%%~x.sum.rpt" or "!_OutFile!".

Comment: My apologies once again - the script does work with >"%%~x.sum.rpt".  I had one of the Excel sheet open and it kept giving me an error.  This should be my last comment of the day.  :)